# Trigger event outside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event named `quantity_changed`. I want to trigger this, I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.plus').bind("mouseup", function() {

        quantity_changed();

    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. Clearly I'm not calling the function correctly. `quantity_changed` can be found in the following code:

```
var tribe_event_tickets_plus = tribe_event_tickets_plus || {};
tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta = tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta || {};
tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event = tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event || {};

(function ( window, document, $, my ) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Initializes the meta functionality
     */
    my.init = function() {
        $( '.tribe-list' ).on( 'click', '.attendee-meta.toggle', function() {
            $( this )
                .toggleClass( 'on' )
                .siblings( '.attendee-meta-row' )
                .slideToggle();
        });

        this.$ticket_form = $( '.tribe-events-tickets' ).closest( '.cart' );

        this.$ticket_form
            .on( 'change', '.quantity input, .quantity select', this.event.quantity_changed )
            .on( 'keyup', '.quantity input', this.event.quantity_changed )
            .on( 'submit', this.event.handle_submission );

        this.$ticket_form.find( '.quantity input:not([type="hidden"]), .quantity select' ).each( function() {
            my.set_quantity( $( this ) );
        } );

        $( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields' ).on( 'keydown', '.tribe-tickets-meta-number input', this.event.limit_number_field_typing );
    };

    my.render_fields = function( ticket_id, num ) {
        var $row = $( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta' ).filter( '[data-ticket-id="' + ticket_id + '"]' );
        var $template = $row.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields-tpl' );
        var $fields = $row.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields' );
        var template_html = $template.html();

        if ( ! my.has_meta_fields( ticket_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        var current_count = $fields.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-attendee' ).length;
        var diff = 0;

        if ( current_count > num ) {
            diff = current_count - num;

            $fields.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-attendee:nth-last-child(-n+' + diff + ')' ).remove();
            return;
        }

        diff = num - current_count;

        var i = 0;
        for ( ; i < diff; i++ ) {
            var tweaked_template_html = template_html;
            tweaked_template_html = template_html.replace( /tribe-tickets-meta\[\]/g, 'tribe-tickets-meta[' + ticket_id + '][' + ( current_count + i + 1 ) + ']' );
            tweaked_template_html = tweaked_template_html.replace( /tribe-tickets-meta_([a-z0-9\-]+)_/g, 'tribe-tickets-meta_$1_' + ( current_count + i + 1 ) + '_' );
            $fields.append( tweaked_template_html );
        }
    };

    my.set_quantity = function( $field ) {
        var quantity = parseInt( $field.val(), 10 );
        var ticket_id = parseInt( $field.closest( 'td' ).data( 'product-id' ), 10 );
        var template_html = $( document.getElementById( 'tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields-tpl-' + ticket_id ) ).html();

        if ( quantity && my.has_meta_fields( ticket_id ) ) {
            $field.closest( 'table' ).find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta[data-ticket-id="' + ticket_id +'"]' ).show();
        } else {
            $field.closest( 'table' ).find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta[data-ticket-id="' + ticket_id +'"]' ).hide();
        }

        my.render_fields( ticket_id, quantity );
    };

    my.has_meta_fields = function( ticket_id ) {
        var template_html = $( document.getElementById( 'tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields-tpl-' + ticket_id ) ).html();
        return !! $( template_html ).find( '.tribe-tickets-meta' ).length;
    };

    /**
     * Validates the required fields for custom meta
     */
    my.validate_submission = function() {
        var is_valid = true;
        var $fields = $( '.tribe-tickets-meta-required' );

        $fields.each( function() {
            var $el = $( this );
            var val = '';

            if ( $el.is( '.tribe-tickets-meta-radio' ) || $el.is( '.tribe-tickets-meta-checkbox' ) ) {
                val = $el.find( 'input:checked' ).length ? 'checked' : '';
            } else {
                val = $el.find( 'input, select, textarea' ).val();
            }

            if ( 0 === val.length ) {
                is_valid = false;
            }
        } );

        return is_valid;
    };

    my.event.quantity_changed = function() {
        my.set_quantity( $( this ) );
    };

    /**
     * Ensure that only whole numbers can be entered into the number field
     */
    my.event.limit_number_field_typing = function( e ) {
        if (
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            $.inArray( e.keyCode, [ 46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110 ] ) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            ( e.keyCode === 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            ( e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true ) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            ( e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey === true ) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            ( e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true ) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            ( e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40 )
        ) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ( ( e.shiftKey || ( e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57 ) ) && ( e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105 ) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Event to handle the submission action
     *
     * Validates required meta fields and stores meta data into cookies
     */
    my.event.handle_submission = function( e ) {
        if ( ! my.validate_submission() ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $( this ).closest( 'form' );

            $form.addClass( 'tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-missing-required' );

            $( 'html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $form.offset().top
            }, 300 );
            return;
        }

        var $meta_groups = $( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta' );

        $meta_groups.each( function() {
            var $group = $( this );
            var ticket_id = $group.data( 'ticket-id' );
            var $attendees = $group.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-attendee' );

            if ( ! $attendees.length ) {
                return;
            }

            var data = $attendees.find( 'input, select, textarea' ).serialize();

            var key = 'tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-' + ticket_id;

            var current = $.cookie( key );

            current = current ? $.deparam( current ) : null;

            if ( current && current.hasOwnProperty( 'tribe-tickets-meta' ) ) {
                data = $.deparam( data );

                if (
                    current.hasOwnProperty( 'tribe-tickets-meta' )
                    && data.hasOwnProperty( 'tribe-tickets-meta' )
                    && 'undefined' !== typeof current['tribe-tickets-meta'][ ticket_id ]
                    && 'undefined' !== typeof data['tribe-tickets-meta'][ ticket_id ]
                ) {
                    data['tribe-tickets-meta'][ ticket_id ].forEach( function( el, index, collection ) {
                        current['tribe-tickets-meta'][ ticket_id ].push( el );
                    } );

                    data = $.param( current );
                }
            } else {
                $.removeCookie( key );
            }

            // $.param does some weird stuff when converting a non-0 indexed array
            data = data.replace( /(tribe-tickets-meta\%5B\%5D\=\&)+/, '' );

            // $.param does some weird stuff when converting a non-0 indexed array
            data = data.replace( new RegExp( '(tribe-tickets-meta\%5B' + ticket_id + '\%5D\%5B\%5D\=\&)+' ), '' );

            $.cookie( key, data, {
                expires: 1,
                path: '/'
            } );
        } );
    };

    $( function() {
        my.init();
    } );
} )( window, document, jQuery, tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta );
```

Comment: `quantity_changed()` is not available in the scope where you're binding the event. Why can't you bind to `.plus` when it *does* available (like the other handlers)?

Comment: @haim770 Can you please write an answer demonstrating your solution? I am not sure I understand your approach. Thanks.

Comment: From the outside of that IFFE tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event. quantity_changed() looks like the access path to that function.  Have you tried that?

Comment: It's not really a "solution". One has to determine first, why is the (`$('.plus').bind("mouseup", ...`) event bound separately? (Although `tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event.quantity_changed()` might work).

Comment: @ScottFanetti No I haven't, can you kindly write up an answer?

Comment: I agree with haim70 that should probably be in the init function.

Comment: @haim770  Unfortunately I can't add it within the function because it is a separate file (not my own script). I only aim to call that function if you get my drift.

Answer (score 0):

The method is a property of `tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event`

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.plus').bind("mouseup", function() {

        tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event.quantity_changed();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access that function - its not available in the global scope.  You have to access it via the path of the object on which you attached it.

```
 tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event.quantity_changed()
```

If your document.ready is after the declaration of tribe_event_tickets_plus it will see and have access to that function.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your entire code, I see two potential issues here.

1. `quantity_changed` is set to be owned by `my.event`. However, I don't see `my.event` being defined anywhere in your sample. It's possible that it's defined elsewhere, but make sure it exists before you attempt to add the `quantity_changed` method to it.
2. When you call `quantity_changed`, you're not specifying which object owns it, so the JS engine must assume that the function is owned by the window. In your case, you'd want to do something along the lines of:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('.plus').bind("mouseup", function() {
           my.event.quantity_changed();
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: `my` is not available in that scope. You probably meant `tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta.event.quantity_changed()`

Comment: `my` is undefined outside the IIFE

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the IFFE tribe_event_tickets_plus.meta  is passed as the parameter my

Comment: Ah, yep. My bad. Still though, the point is that the function can't simply be called by referencing its name. The owner of the function needs to be defined, whatever it is.